# Banner won't save cookies after closing

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies, banner

```js
(() => {
  const getCookie = (name) => {
    const value = " " + document.cookie;
    console.log("value", `==${value}==`);
    const parts = value.split(" " + name + "=");
    return parts.length < 2 ? undefined : parts.pop().split(";").shift();
  };

  const setCookie = function (name, value, expiryDays, domain, path, secure) {
    const exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setHours(
      exdate.getHours() +
        (typeof expiryDays !== "number" ? 365 : expiryDays) * 30
    );
    document.cookie =
      name +
      "=" +
      value +
      ";expires=" +
      exdate.toUTCString() +
      ";path=" +
      (path || "/") +
      (domain ? ";domain=" + domain : "") +
      (secure ? ";secure" : "");
  };

  const $cookiesBanner = document.querySelector(".newsletter-banner");
  const $cookiesBannerButton = $cookiesBanner.querySelector("#bannerClose");
  const cookieName = "cookiesBanner";
  const hasCookie = getCookie(cookieName);

  if (!hasCookie) {
    $cookiesBanner.classList.remove("banner-hide");
  }

  $cookiesBannerButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    setCookie(cookieName, "closed");
    $cookiesBanner.remove();
  });
})();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10%;
    
  }
  
  .newsletter-banner  {
    background: url("banner_pop_up.png") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    color: #fff;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 0 3% 0;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 10000;
    opacity:0;
    animation:show 3s 3s forwards;
    transition: .5s;
  }

   /* Banner Close button*/
  .banner_close { 
    color: #e30616; 
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .banner_close:hover {
    color: #4A4A49;
  }

  .banner_buttonbox
  {
    padding: 2% 5% 8% 0;
    width: 35px; 
    float: right;
  }

  #bannerHide{
    visibility: hidden;
  }


  /* End of Banner Close button*/

.banner_cta 
{
  padding: 0 5% 5% 5%;
}
  
 @keyframes show {
    to {opacity:1}
  }

   
  .banner-hide {
    display: none;
  }


  /* Medium devices (tablets, 579px and up) for the pop banner*/
@media (min-width: 579px) {
  
  .banner_close { 
    color: #e30616; 
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .banner_buttonbox
  {
    padding: 2% 7% 8% 0;
  }
 
.banner_cta
{
  padding: 0 4% 4% 4%;
}

  .newsletter-banner {
    padding: 10%;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 20% 3% 20%;
    width: auto;
  }


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This is the title of the webpage</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cookiebanner.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 

  </head>
  <body>

<br><br><br><br>
    <div>
     
      
      
  



      <br> <br>

      <p>Test site</p>
      <p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p>
      <p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p>
      <p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p><p>Test site</p>
    </div>
   
    
        
      <div class="newsletter-banner banner-hide shadow-lg">
      
        <div id="bannerHide" class="containter">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-10">
              <!---Empty div to space out trigger-->
            </div> 
            <div class="col-2">
  
              <div class="banner_buttonbox">
                <!--(the close button) This is a google font, find the CDN in header includes-->
                <i id="bannerClose" class="material-icons banner_close" style="font-size:35px;">highlight_off</i>
              </div>
  
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
               <!--Start of banner CTA-->
                  <div class="banner_cta">
                  <h2>Be the first to know when we post new articles</h2>
                  <p><em>Susbscribe to our knowlegde Base and industry insights</em></p>
  
                  <button id="" style="background-color: red;color: #fff;">Susbscribe</button>
                  </div>
                
               <!---End of Banner CTA--->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      
      </div>
    

    <script src="cookie.js"></script>
   
    
    <script>
    
    const banner = document.getElementById('bannerHide');

    setTimeout(() => {
      banner.style.visibility = 'visible';  //  Changes CSS property in the ID #bannerHide

    }, 3000); //  delay in milliseconds

    </script>


  
   

  </body>
</html>
```

I have created a banner with CSS and JS. The idea is to save cookies for 30days after user hits the close button but for some reason the cookies is not saving.

I want the banner to close and not pop up again until after 30days of the user clicking the close button.

See CodePen

https://codepen.io/timt360/full/MWPEMYq